# Azure Authentication between two Web Apps

Tags: ajax, azure, authentication

I've set up two Web Apps in Azure and both are backed by Azure AD Authentication.
One is the frontend and the second is the API backend. Opening every page on their own works well (Login screen), but calls made by the frontend to the backend results in being blocked by CORS policy. Message is:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load hxxps://backend.azurewebsites.com/api. Redirect from hxxps://backend.azurewebsites.com/api to hxxps://login.windows.net/94... has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'hxxps://frontend.azurewebsites.net' is therefore not allowed access.

The call is made as follows:

```
$.ajax({
            type: type,
            dataType: 'json',
            url: server + '/' + url,
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            data: data
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API should not be sending back redirects when a call is unauthenticated. The caller can't do anything useful with that.

Instead you should setup Azure AD Bearer token authentication on the API, with `Audience` set to the APIs client id, and the `Tenant` set to your Azure AD tenant id/domain name.

Then your front-end should get an access token for the API somehow, and attach it to all calls going to it. There are multiple ways to do this.

Here you can find a sample Single-Page application: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp.

More sample apps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples

Comment: Thanks, got it! :)